# Visual Studio 2008 - form tool that allows you to locate a file on your drive

Tags: visual-studio-2008

What is the name of the tool that you can load on a form, that when a user clicks it it allows them to find a find by navigatin the drive?  And if I remember rightly don't I have to add a reference to the project to find it??  Just can't remember the name...

I am using visual studio 2008, c# project.

Thanks, R

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenFileDialog is the name, there is also FolderBrowserDialog

see image

[image]

Comment: That is excellent, thanks.  It actually was the folder browser dialog that was what I wanted in the end.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).